# I get error on build that mvc assembly version postal is using is higher than referenced by my project. How do I resolve this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using mvc 4 asp.net.

I have used postal.dll package from NuGet to send emails from my application.

But I get error on build that mvc assembly version postal is using is higher than referenced by my project. How do I resolve this? please help

I am using Visual studio 2012 mvc4

Thanks

Error:

> Error 1   Assembly 'Postal, Version=0.9.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=45719375b8b4d528' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'   c:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProject\packages\postal.0.9.2\lib\net40\Postal.dll MyProject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your message is telling you is that `Postal, Version=0.9.2.0,` works with version `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0,` but you gave it `System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0` so it broke.

If you have two different assembly versions you might want to do [binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<bindingRedirect  
   oldVersion="existing assembly version"
   newVersion="new assembly version"/>
```

Other option would be to use `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0` across your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an older version of Postal, assuming it satisfies your requirements.

```
Install-Package postal -Version 0.9.0
```